# "Could": conditional or past simple?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> I thought of you as everything I've had but **could** not keep
>
> Lou Reed: Pale Blue Eyes

Is **could** past simple or conditional? I think it is past simple because **have had** means I've just lost you.

Comment: You understand this correctly. You may paraphrase it as "everything which I've ever had but was unable to keep".

Comment: So i am a bit  surprised why it is not   had had  Can we say  I ve had this camera for ten weeks when I sold it

Comment: The verbforms are ambiguous. In the original recording by the Velvet Underground there is no "I" at the head of this line, and in later performances Reed himself sings "**I've** thought of you", not "I thought of you". The key thing is that the woman addressed, whom the singer appears to have regarded previously as something he had that he *could* keep, has now entered the category of things he has had and could not keep. ... And No, your camera sentence is not grammatical.

Comment: So that is why he uses past simple for could .He realised that this love is ending or has just  ended and that  this love  belongs ALREADY to the past for him.

Comment: "Could" is only conditional in a conditional construction. The sentence you quote is not a conditional construction. Here, "could" talks about past ability, similar to *wasn't able to keep*.

Answer (score 1):

> Is **could** past simple or conditional?

As @StoneyB relates in his comment, you are correct that this is the past simple form of the word ***can***.

> Can we say "I've had this camera for ten weeks when I sold it?"

No, this in ungrammatical. As the process of you having the camera *stops* at that given point in the past when you sold it, using the *present perfect* tense is inappropriate. Ditch the contracted **have** to fix it and you'd be fine:

> I had the camera for ten weeks when I sold it.